# Can jvm optimization change order of instructions?

Tags: java, optimization, logging, jvm

I was remotely debugging Java application and debugger showed me different information than I expected. Source file was linked correctly. Is it possible, that jvm optimization can change order of instructions?

Comment: Logging libraries generally use some form of synchronization so it is unlikely that logging instructions would be reordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends.

The JVM (especially Hotspot or a JIT compiler) may change instructions if it can determine that the result will be the same.

With the Oracle JVM you can give the option `-Xint` which disables the JIT and Hotspot and you can be sure that the code executed is the same as written.

Answer (score 0):

When for example debugging remotely, I experienced inconsistencies when I made changes to my code, which were not pushed to server, yet. So when I debugged the older version on my server, the debugger sometimes pointed to lines in my code that were either empty or were in a different method because it still refered to the previously relevant line numbers. 
When I synchronised the server and my local code repository, everything was fine again.